# How do I determine independence without computing $f_X (x)$ and $f_Y(y)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be the percentage of completion of a certain task in an airtight factory machine, and let $Y$ be the pressure in the closed space in atmospheres (where 1 atmosphere is 101.325 kPa). Take $X$ and $Y$ as two random variables with the following joint probability density function. Assume $k$ is a constant multiplier which satisfies that the density integrates to $1$. For this question you do not have to determine what $k$ is.

$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}   \quad k[(xy)^2 e^{x+y}\ln(y^x)+y^2\cdot e^y\cdot \ln(y)], \ \  0.5\leq  x \leq 1 \leq  y \leq  1.5 \\ \quad
0, \  \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

(a) Are the percentage of completion of the task and the pressure in the chamber independent? Show your reasoning.

(b) What is the correlation between the percentage completion of the task and the pressure in the chamber? If you need to use k you do not need to solve for k.

(c) Feel free to define a as a constant multiplier so that the marginal density $f_X (x)$ integrates to 1, and define b as a constant multiplier so that the marginal density $f_Y (y)$ integrates to 1. Without having to solve for a or b, write these two marginal density functions. How do a and b relate to k?

for part a)

I understand to determine independence, 
$f(x,y)= f(x)f(y)$
but, what other way is there to determine this, the integration is hefty.

Comment: Try to simplify the formula for $f(x,y)$.  Pull out common factors.

Comment: I´ve made an edit. Please check if my work is right.

Comment: Also note that $\ln(y^x)=x\cdot \ln(y)$. If you integrate w.r.t y then you can put in front the integral the factors with the variable $x$.

Comment: No need to integrate, just collect together the $x$ and $y$ terms: $f(x,y) =  k(y^2 e^y\ln y)(1 + x^3e^x)$, which implies independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @dnqxt That´s true.